# When to dispose of ValueNotifier in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a ValueNotifier in a State object that I listen to with ValueListenableBuilder.  It is used to read data from firestore.  When the user clicks next I allocate a new notifier (without disposing of the old one)  and call setState to rerun the build method and make it listen to the new notifier.  I'm having difficulty figuring out if anything could go wrong here.  e.g. suppose a prior notifier hadn't completed but completes before the build method triggered by the new setState gets to run   - does that cause a problem ??  - will the build method run twice and start listening to the new notifier after the second run?  Should I dispose of the old notifier before allocating a new one?  And also when the code for the first one completes will the associated Notifier be collected up by the garbage collector - or will it hang around forever because it thinks it has listeners?

Example code is below

```
class MyNotifier extends ValueNotifier<int>{
  MyNotifier() : super(-1);
}
class Result {
}

void f1(String path, Result? data1, MyNotifier note) async {
  DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>  doc1 = await firestoreDb.doc(path).get();
  // ... copy doc1 data to data1
  note.value = 1;
}

class X1 extends StatefulWidget {
    X1();
    @override
    State<X1> createState()
    {
      return _X1();
    }
}

class _X1 extends State<X1> {

  MyNotifier note1 = MyNotifier();

  MyNotifier newNote1() {
    note1.dispose();  // ??
    return note1 = MyNotifier();
  }

  void someUserAction()  {
    // ...
    f1("abc", null, newNote1());
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context1) {
    return ValueListenableBuilder(
      valueListenable: note1,
      builder: (context2, value, child) {
        return Text("");
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: ^this + show us the code

Comment: it's a lot of code, I'll try and write a compact equivalent and add it to the question.

Comment: updated with some example code

Comment: Instead of creating a new notifier, why not just pass the existing one into your f1 method and update the value?

Comment: The reason for creating a new one is f1 might get called a second time before the first f1 one has completed  - then I need the first one to leave the notifier alone if it is late completing.